# Android Studio Task failed with an exception

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I Can't Run My Android Studio App. Task failed with an exception. gives the error
Here is it error:

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.android.support:design-v4:28.0.0.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/design-v4/28.0.0/design-v4-28.0.0.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/support/design-v4/28.0.0/design-v4-28.0.0.pom
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/design-v4/28.0.0/design-v4-28.0.0.pom
> Required by:
> project :app

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

```
here is my build.gradle (module)

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.gokturkolmz.ucuzal"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:design-v4:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

PLEASE HELP !!!

Comment: The library you are trying to add does not exist.  There is no `design-v4` library.  Also, the `android.support` libraries are all deprecated, no longer receiving bug fixes or new features, and should not be used in new code.  You should [migrate to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).

Answer (score 0):

I did not see `design-v4` from maven central (and you minSdk-23 does not require v4 fallback support), below is the correct one:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

Check its maven central records: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support/design/28.0.0